# Observables de Alto Nivel RXJS - Obtener información de dos fuentes de datos

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

Estoy intentando comprender los Observables de Orden Superior de RXJS. Después de ver muchos vídeos y manuales, ya entiendo que los Observables de Orden Superior son aquellos observables que emiten otros observables (en lugar de valores). También entiendo los conceptos de Observables externos e internos.

Hasta aquí todo correcto. Me he ido recorriendo los Observables de Orden Superior y he intentado hacerme un ejemplo "más o menos real", rebajando la complejidad, para poder entender sus diferencias.

El artículo que he utilizado como base es el de esta web (https://pablomagaz.com/blog/combinando-observables-en-rxjs).

- He creado los observables usuarios y aficiones, y una función para buscar aficiones:

```
let usuarios$ = of({nombre: 'Antonio',
                    aficion: 'Senderismo',
                    domicilio: 'Madrid'},
                   {nombre: 'Maria',
                    aficion: 'Musica',
                    domicilio: 'Paracuellos'},
                   {nombre: 'Fernando',
                    aficion: 'escalada',
                    domicilio: 'Madrid'},
                   {nombre: 'Juan',
                    aficion: 'Jardineria',
                    domicilio: 'Madrid'}
);

let aficiones$ = of({aficion: 'Senderismo',
                     rutas: ['Siete Picos','Las Machotas']},
                    {aficion: 'Musica',
                     grupos: ['Clasica','ColdPlay']},
                    {aficion: 'Jardineria',
                     grupos: ['Geranios','Nabos']},
                    {aficion: 'Informatica',
                     lenguajes: ['Javascript','Python']
                    } 
);

function buscarAficion(aficion){
   return aficiones$.pipe(
      filter( resp => resp.aficion === aficion)
   );
}
```

Con MergeAll he creado el siguiente código para aplanar los observables:

```
usuarios$.pipe(
   map(usuario => buscarAficion(usuario.aficion)),
   mergeAll()
).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

El resultado es satisfactorio. Sólo salen del segundo observable los que están en el primero:

```
{…}
​
aficion: "Senderismo"
​
rutas: Array [ "Siete Picos", "Las Machotas" ]
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
script.js:186:28
{…}
​
aficion: "Musica"
​
grupos: Array [ "Clasica", "ColdPlay" ]
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
script.js:186:28
{…}
​
aficion: "Jardineria"
​
grupos: Array [ "Geranios", "Nabos" ]
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

El problema está cuando quiero que en la salida me muestre datos del primer observable y del segundo (la idea es que fuesen dos llamadas a servicios REST y sacar una información a partir de ellos).

- Intento hacer lo siguiente:

```
usuarios$.pipe(
   map(usuario => { return {nombre: usuario.nombre,
                     aficion: usuario.aficion,
                     data: buscarAficion(usuario.aficion)}
   }),
   mergeAll()
).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Y me da el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

He intentado otras cosas y tampoco han funcionado. ¿Cómo se podría combinar la información de estas dos fuentes?

Gracias.

Comment: Tampoco funciona esto otro: usuarios$.pipe(
   mergeMap(
      usuario => {
         buscarAficion(usuario.aficion)
            .map(aficiones => {
               return {
                  nombre: usuario.nombre,
                  aficion: usuario.aficion,
                  aficiones: aficiones.lista
               }
         })   
      }
   )
)
.subscribe(
   resp => console.log(resp)
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de romperme mucho la cabeza, he conseguido que el código funcione.

Adjunto el código completo totalmente funcional:

- Código HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Pruebas</h1>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.3/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

- Código Javascript (script.js):

```
window.addEventListener('load',inicio);

const { Observable, interval, from } = rxjs;
const { tap, take, mergeMap, map } = rxjs.operators;


class Persona{
    constructor(nombre, edad, aficion){
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.edad = edad;
      this.aficion = aficion;
    }  
}  
  
class Aficion{
     constructor(nombre,lista){
       this.nombre = nombre;
       this.lista = lista;
     }  
}
  
let personas = [new Persona('Antonio',42,'Lectura'),
                new Persona('Patri',43,'Senderismo'),
                new Persona('Fer',47,'Escalada'),
                new Persona('Maria',46,'Musica')
];
  
let posibilidades = [
    new Aficion('Lectura', ['It','Tierra','22/11/63']),
    new Aficion('Senderismo',['Las Cabrillas','Cerro Larda']),
    new Aficion('Musica',['ColdPlay','Clásica'])  
];  
  
function usuarios$(){
    return interval(1000).pipe(
       take(4),
       map(pos => personas[pos])    
    );
}
  
  
function aficiones$(aficion){
    let aficiones = [];
   
    posibilidades.forEach(
      (afic) => {
        if (afic.nombre === aficion){
          aficiones.push(afic);
        }  
      }  
    )
   
    return from(aficiones);
}

function inicio(){

    usuarios$().pipe(
        mergeMap(
            usuario => {
            return aficiones$(usuario.aficion).pipe(
                map(
                    aficion => {
                        return {
                                usuario: usuario.nombre,
                                aficion: aficion.nombre,
                                posibilidades: aficion.lista 
                        };
                    }
                )
            )
            }  
        )
    ).subscribe(
        val =>  console.log(JSON.stringify(val))
    );
}
```

Esta es la sálida en consola del código resultante:

```
{"usuario":"Antonio","aficion":"Lectura","posibilidades":["It","Tierra","22/11/63"]} 
{"usuario":"Patri","aficion":"Senderismo","posibilidades":["Las Cabrillas","Cerro 
{"usuario":"Maria","aficion":"Musica","posibilidades":["ColdPlay","Clásica"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con

```
usuarios$
    .pipe(
        switchMap(usuario =>
            buscarAficion(usuario.aficion)
                .pipe(
                    map(data => ({
                        data,
                        nombre: usuario.nombre,
                        aficion: usuario.aficion
                    }))
                )
        )
    )
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: No es el operador que quería usar. Lo acabo de solucionar. Gracias de todas formas

Comment: Para búsquedas de datos en tiempo real debes evitar mergeMap y usar switchMap